# Adding an arraylist to the preferences

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to add an arraylist to the preferences of my app...

At first the list should be empty, but then the user can add items, 
which will be saved to the preferences...

and then the next time the user launches the app, he'll see the list that he created earlier...

Thanx upfront.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have any sample code...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[SharedPreferences.Editor.putStringSet (String key, Set values)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.Editor.html#putStringSet%28java.lang.String,%20java.util.Set%3Cjava.lang.String%3E%29)